# Adobe Air for desktop: what's easiest way to enable application updates for end users?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I have a Flex app that runs in a user's desktop browser. I want to create an AIR desktop app out of it for Windows and Mac.

I'm new to AIR. I'm using Flex 4.10 and Flash Builder 4.7.

This link:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/air_buildingapps.pdf

states on PDF page 244:

```
Users can install or update an AIR application by double-clicking an AIR file 
on their computer or from the browser (using the seamless install feature). The 
Adobe® AIR® installer application manages the installation, alerting the user if 
they are updating an already existing application.

However, you can also have an installed application update itself to a new 
version, using the Updater class.
```

The first sentence is what I'm trying to achieve. I believe the "seamless installer" enables the user to update the application by clicking an icon on a webpage. That's fine. What about the first part of the first sentence... `Users can install or update an AIR application by double-clicking an AIR file on their computer...` What do I need to do to get that part working?

Because the next sentence starts "However, you can also...", I don't think Chapter 17 discusses this. I want to avoid doing anything custom if something already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe made this for us:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdaterUI.html

This is the easiest and very professional solution

I think I saw different types of this Updater (Open source maybe?) - Very good too!

Good Luck!!

Comment: OK, then this is essentially Chapter 17 in the question's link above. Then the `However, you can also...` seems misleading as it implies the chapter discusses something different. So then, correct me if I'm wrong, this link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html is the way to go for Flex?

Comment: Your link is a wonderful tutorial that based on the link of the language reference that in my answer.. I love their tutorials so if I needed to do it, I was using your link!